# decimal to base64 conversion for H.264

Tags: base64, h.264

How are sps/pps in H264 converted to base64? I couldn't find this on the specs.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

RFC 6184 mentions this in [8.1. Media Type Registration](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184#section-8.1):

> ```
>   sprop-parameter-sets:
>      This parameter MAY be used to convey any sequence and picture
>      parameter set NAL units (herein referred to as the initial
>      parameter set NAL units) that can be placed in the NAL unit
>      stream to precede any other NAL units in decoding order.  The
>      parameter MUST NOT be used to indicate codec capability in any
>      capability exchange procedure.  The value of the parameter is a
>      comma-separated (',') list of base64 [7] representations of
>      parameter set NAL units as specified in Sections 7.3.2.1 and
>      7.3.2.2 of [1].  Note that the number of bytes in a parameter
>      set NAL unit is typically less than 10, but a picture parameter
>      set NAL unit can contain several hundred bytes.
> ```

[Base64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) is used in a straightforward way: it takes binary data on input (raw SPS/PPS byte arrays) and outputs text to be, for instance, a part of SDP.

Comment: do you know when preamble is necessary? I know it is 0,0,0,1 but I'm not sure if it's only necessary when sending those parameters in-band.

Comment: No, start code prefixes `0x000001` should not be there. Actually, here is the value example: `sprop-parameter-sets=Z0KAKNoC0EkQ,aM48gA==` and as you can see the second one is too short to hold start code prefix.

Comment: do you know where it is stated that 0,0,0,1 need to be used only for in-band transmissions? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: It is unlikely to be stated like this. It is NAL units, and they are defined in MPEG-4 Part 10 secification, in a way that start code prefixes are defined additionally.

Comment: the 000001 is the Annex.B start code.  It is used in MPEG transport streams.  It is not used in MP4 files.  Based on the example provided by Roman R. there is no 000001 prefix.      perl -e 'use MIME::Base64; $decoded = decode_base64(shift); print "$decoded\n"' Z0KAKNoC0EkQ | od -t x1    gives me 67 42 80 28 da 02 d0 49 10 0a

Comment: I still don't understand when the preamble is used. Is it part of the SPS, or is it something you need to add if you want to transmit SPS/PPS in-band?